# How to enable multiple Content-Types for a response in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, rest

I have a simple `@RestController` and would like to response with both `JSON` or `XML` depending on the http header `content-type`.

Problem: I'm always only getting `XML` response, never JSON. Of course I'm using `Content-Type: application/json` as http header.

What might be missing in the following configuration?

```
@RestController
public void MyServlet {

    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public MyResponse test() {
        return new MyResponse();
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class MyResponse {
    private String test = "somevalue";
    //getter, setter
}
```

pom.xml:

```
       <!-- as advised in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Interestingly: if I switch the produces statement:
`produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})`,
then I'm always getting `JSON` out and never `XML`!

So the question is: why does the first MediaType always have precedence, and the http header is never taken into account?

Comment: Splitting methods for JSON and XML or this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676613/multiple-scenarios-requestmapping-produces-json-xml-together-with-accept-or-res

Comment: Just curious - shouldnt you use `Accept` header insteed of content type ?

Comment: Hah i just saw likend answer and guess i was right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you should use `Accept` header not `Content-Type`.

On a request, the `Accept` header is used to request the `Content-Type` of the response from the server.

On a request the `Content-Type` is used to define the structure of the request body.

Comment: Wow, great catch. That's indeed the solution!